# Show that ordered pairs are solutions to an equation if and only if they are consecutive elements of a recursive sequence (contest question)

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

The following question appeared on the 1998 Canada National Olympiad. I need help proving that the **only** solutions to the equation are consecutive elements of the recursively-defined sequence. I believe that the claim has been proven in the if-direction.

> Let $m$ be a positive integer. Define the sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots$ by
>
> $a_0 = 0 \tag{1}$
>
> $a_1=m \tag{2}$
>
> $a_{n+1} = m^2 a_n−a_{n−1} \tag{3}$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ .
>
> **Prove that an ordered pair $(a, b)$ of non-negative integers, with $a \le b$, gives a solution to the equation**
>
> $\dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{ab + 1} = m^2 \tag{4}$
>
> **if and only if $(a, b)$ is of the form $(a_n, a_{n+1})$ for some $n \ge 0$**.

---

#### Sequence $\{a_n\}$

$\begin{align}
a_0 &= 0 \\
a_1 &= m \\
a_2 &= m^3 \\
a_3 &= m^5 - m \\
a_4 &= m^7 - 2m^3 \\
a_5 &= m^9 - 3m^5 + m \\
\dots
\end{align}$

#### Case m=1

Noting that $(a-b)(a-b) = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \ge 0$ we have $a^2+b^2 \ge 2ab \ge ab+1$ with equality only when $a=b=1$ or $a=0,b=1$, for $m=1$ equation (4) has only the trivial solution $(a,b)=(0,1),(1,1)$. It can easily be shown that every element of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ belongs to $\{-1,0,-1\}$, with a $-1$ and $1$ (and vice-versa) never being in succession. If $(-1,0)$ was allowed, it would also be a solution of (4).

#### Case m>1

Let $S$ be the set of all ordered pairs satisfying (4) for a given $m$.

Proceed by induction to show that all pairs $(a_n, a_{n+1}) \in S$.
The induction hypothesis is

$IH: (a_n, a_{n+1}) \in S\text{ for } n \ge 0.$

For the base case, clearly $(a_0, a_1) \in S$.

Now assume IH for $n$, and investigate the truth of IH for $n+1$, i.e. whether $(a_{n+1}, a_{n+2})$ satisfies (4). For the left-hand side:

$L = \dfrac{{a_{n+1}}^2+{a_{n+2}}^2}{{a_{n+1}}{a_{n+2}}+1} = \dfrac{{a_{n+1}}^2+(m^2a_{n+1}-a_n)^2}{{a_{n+1}}(m^2a_{n+1}-a_n)+1} = \dfrac{(1+m^4){a_{n+1}}^2-2m^2a_n{a_{n+1}}+{a_n}^2}{m^2{a_{n+1}}^2-a_n{a_{n+1}}+1}$

so

$L = m^2 + \dfrac{{a_{n+1}}^2-m^2a_n{a_{n+1}}+{a_n}^2-m^2}{m^2{a_{n+1}}^2-a_n{a_{n+1}}+1} = m^2 + \dfrac{{a_{n+1}}^2+{a_n}^2-m^2(a_n{a_{n+1}}+1)}{m^2{a_{n+1}}^2-a_n{a_{n+1}}+1}$

By the induction hypothesis, the numerator of the last term is zero, so $(a_{n+1},a_{n+2})$ is a solution of (4) too. So $(a_{n+1},a_{n+2}) \in S$ and the induction hypothesis is true for $n+1$, proving the induction step.

Therefore $(a_n, a_{n+1})$ is a solution for all $n \ge 0$.

Comment: Ha, IMO 1988 P6 strikes again.

Comment: That sounds ominous.

Comment: Your problem is [related to](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-toughest-problem-ever-asked-in-an-IMO) one of the most notorious IMO problems of all time.